# Analytics Bounce and Exit at 100%

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have some weird situation in my Google Analytics.

In that website, we use an async POST call to "https: //www.google-analytics.com/collect?z=randomNumber" on page load. All the page views, referrer, titles etc. are right, but the "bounce", "Enter page" and "Exit page" are all wrong.

Some test results in all pages be the enter and the exit pages.

This is the post request:

```
t: "pageview"
v: "1"
tid: "UA-00000000-0"
cid: "XXX" //Stored in session, same in all the user requests
dp: "/it/home"
ds: "web"
dr: "https://www.XXXXXX.com/it/chi-siamo"
sr: "1366x744"
vp: "1361x393"
de: "UTF-8"
sd: "24-bits"
ul: "it"
dh: "www.XXXXXX.com"
dt: "Home+-+XXXXXX"
fl: ""
uip: "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX"
ua: "Mozilla/5.0+XXXXXXXX"
```

What is wrong with this data?
Thanks

EDIT:
I have done some test, same JS code, different domain, in the second domain, the result was perfect:
Domain with error: do-ma-in.com
Domain works fine: domain.com.br

Answer (score 0):

Resolved!

The "DR" parameter have to be sent just if document.referrer.hostname (retrieved from document.referrer) is different from document.location.hostname.